# J2ME DataOutputStream from FileConnection encoding

Tags: file, java-me, midp, dataoutputstream, jsr75

I'm trying to write some data into DataOutputStream from FileConnection.

```
FileConnection con = (FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///C:/file.txt");
   if (!con.exists())
con.create();
DataOutputStream out = con.openDataOutputStream();
out.writeUTF("some text");
out.close();
con.close();
```

But rather than the text I've typed, I receive some garbage in the file - like there are some problems with encoding.
Ok, from what I can see it adds null and 0xFF sign at the start of a file.
What can be the cause?

Answer (score 2):

Please Look at my method for writing Files in Java ME
I think you are missing `Connector.READ_WRITE` in your code,

```
private void writeTextFile(String fileName, String text) 
{
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    FileConnection fconn = null;
    try 
    {
        fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(fileName, Connector.READ_WRITE);
        if (!fconn.exists())
            fconn.create();
        os = fconn.openDataOutputStream();
        os.write(text.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (null != os)
                os.close();
            if (null != fconn)
                fconn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```